# JSP: The value '2.5' of attribute 'version' on element 'web-app' is not valid with respect to its type 'web-app-versionType'

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat

soy nuevo haciendo web con Java y he creado un proyecto con JSP en [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse), tengo el Tomcat 10.0 y la ejecución de la web en el servidor funciona correctamente, el problema es que visualmente el proyecto aparece como si estuviera teniendo un error, específicamente en el archivo  web.xml (Adjunto imagen), gracias de antemano

Intente dando clic derecho , Java EE tools , Generate Deployment... pero esta ultima opcion me aparece desmarcada

[image: Proyecto con error por el archivo web.xml]

Comment: Aveces, esa marca lo pone indicando que el xml no tiene un DTD.  En el menu Window/View agrega `Problems` para que veas cual es el mensaje específico. Debe ser el que te digo. Si es eso no le hagas caso o si te molesta como a mí entra a `preferencias/validación` y desactiva este tipo de validación o simplemente dale clic derecho al archivo web.xml  y en el menu contextual busca `validation` y seleccionas excluir de validación.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Esto consigo al seleccionar mostrar Problems]

Es parte del codigo xml, algun problema de version :/